# Smile Dynamics - forward variance

Tags: stochastic-volatility, term-structure, variance-swap

I was reading [Smile Dynamics II](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1493302) by Lorenzo Bergomi. It is clear to me that on page 2

$$
V_t^{T_1,T_2}=\frac{(T_2-t)V^{T_2}_{t}-(T_1-t)V^{T_1}_{t}}{T_2-T_1}
$$
is the fair strike of a forward-starting variance swap that starts accumulating variance at $T_1>t$ and matures at $T_2>T_1$. However, I find it difficult to conceptualize quantity $\xi_t^T=V_t^{T,T}$. What does it really represent? And why is it a good idea to model a term structure of such quantities in $T$?

Another basic question I had is the following: if the dynamics of $\xi_t^T$ is postulated to be lognormal in the first formula of page 2, then how come we end up with a zero-mean Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process in eq. (2.1)?

Comment: You agree that $\xi_t^{T,T'}$ is the expectation of future variance over the interval ${T,T'}$? So then $\xi_t^T := \xi_t^{T,T} = \lim_{T' \to T}  \xi_t^{T,T'}$ which is the expectation of the future instantaneous variance. Just like forward rates in term structure theory. In regard to the OU process appearing, have you tried deriving it yourself?

Comment: @Frido You are right! Regarding the OU process, it is not clear to me what the starting point in that derivation would be? I mean $\xi_t^T$ is supposed to be a lognormal process and when I solve the SDE I should get $U_t$ instead of $X_t$ in the exponential, it seems to me. Am I wrong? (comment re-written to fix typo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so
$$
d\xi_t^T = \omega e^{-k(T-t)} \xi_t^T dW_t
$$
where $W$ is standard Brownian.
Then, just by applying Ito I hope you can see that
$$
\log \xi_t^T / \xi_0^T = \omega \int_0^t e^{-k(T-u)} dW_u - \frac12 \omega^2 \int_0^t e^{-2k(T-u)} du
$$
Now just write
$$
e^{-k(T-u)} = e^{-k(T-t)}e^{-k(t-u)}
$$
Then
$$
\log \xi_t^T / \xi_0^T = \omega e^{-k(T-t)} X_t - \frac12 \omega^2 e^{-2k(T-t)} E_0[X_t^2]
$$
with $X_t = \int_0^t e^{-k(t-u)} dW_u$ which is an O-U process.

Comment: Do you have any insight on why Bergomi chose that particular form of lognormal process with exponentially decaying volatility?

Comment: @fwd_T Probably because it's the simplest reasonable form and it ensures that at t=T there is no vol of vol, which makes sense because then the forward start varswap expires.

Comment: @fwd_T Sorry, not entirely true what I wrote: there is still vol of vol at t=T, and it will be equal to omega which is the vol of instantaneous variance at T.